# Experience with Query DSL Libraries in Apigee

Tags: querydsl, apigee

I'm faced with a design issue where many of our APIs are using a variety home brewed Query DSL constructs to provide advanced filtering and sorting of the response.

What I'd like to do is provide a standard DSL across multiple APIs based on a scheme more familiar to our app developers and bring some consistency across our APIs.

Naturally, this is going to pose some complexity parsing and transforming DSL queries to our legacy backends.  However, I was hoping to get a jump start by adopting an existing framework to avoid having to write all the query parsing logic ourselves.

Does anyone have experience using any Open Source DSL frameworks that would be compatible with the Apigee platform?

Comment: I'm considering the following design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with Apigee, but [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) could be used as a foundation for your querying DSLs.

It provides a base query model which can be adapted and extended to fit custom querying/storage stargets.

This answer is biased since I am involved with the Querydsl project.

Answer (score 0):

If you backend is MS Stack - then i would recommend you explore [ODATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx) and [StackOverFlow example using ODATA](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx). I found this pretty powerful.

---

I assume you literally do want users to enter straight query - I mean SQL in HTTP request.
REST itself is good entity based querying protocol - a good [REST API itself](https://blog.apigee.com/taglist/rest_api_design) is very useful for users to get a mindmap of entities.

Answer (score 0):

This was the inspiration I needed.  Thanks!

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch